# error: cannot access IBase class file for android.hidl.base.V1_0.IBase not found

Tags: android, android-source

Android O, AOSP. I'm trying to use an HIDL java library inside an application in `frameworks/base`.

According to [the documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl-java/), I've added the HIDL to `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := vendor.myvendor.mylibrary-V1.0-java
```

In the `MainActivity.java`, I include it and try to use:

```
import vendor.myvendor.mylibrary.V1_0.IGood;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        IGood service;
    }
}
```

This code compiles without any errors. But when I try to access some methods, e.g.:

```
import vendor.myvendor.mylibrary.V1_0.IGood;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        IGood service = IGood.getService();
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: cannot access IBase
            IGood server = IGood.getService();
                                ^
class file for android.hidl.base.V1_0.IBase not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add to the `Android.mk` following line:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.hidl.base-V1.0-java-static
```

Also, after that I've got another error: it didn't compile because of proguard. In my case I had to disable it:

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
```

Otherwise, it is needed to create a proguard config and add all `.jar`s, related to HIDL.

After that everything works.

Comment: Do you understand why this works? Why does the hidl library need to be included as a static lib?